# MVC 5 Bundling Setting EnableOptimizations to True results in missing css

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

When I set EnableOptimizations to true, certain css attributes seem to be missing. This is similar to other questions, but for them the entire css files are missing. For my case, it only seems to be certain attributes.

Specifically, the padding on container-fluid from bootstrap.css goes missing. Everything else works fine though.

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
```

I do not have the folder ~Content/css to cause the virtual directory issue as most other answers have stated.